# How to fix artisan? php artisan optimize throws a [ReflectionException]

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-artisan

First of all, this is the actual error in git bash :

```
php artisan optimize

[ReflectionException]
Class hash does not exist
```

None of my artisan command are actually working. Earlier today, it was. Since i'm using git, I tried to find in the code I change what could be the error. No success.

I'm using Laravel 5.4.36
`php -v` : `PHP 7.1.9-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`
`vagrant -v` : `Vagrant 2.0.0`
Homestead version is 6.2.2
Homestead is installed on windows 10.

There is the list of step I tried to solve the problem.
1.`composer dump-autoload` -> FAILED at `php artisan optimize`
2.`composer update` -> FAILED at `php artisan optimize`
3. Check if Hash is present in config\app.php

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    ....
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    ....

'aliases' => [
    ....
    'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    ....
```

3.1 I look if this file exist : `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash` It exist.
3.2 I look if this file exist : `Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher` It exist.
4. I runned `sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache` and `sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache`.
I don't think that step (4) really did something that could help to solve this problem...
5. Tried `composer dump-autoload` again... Still FAILED at `php artisan optimize`
6. I deleted the vendor document then run `composer install` FAILED at `php artisan optimize`
7. I tried to run `php artisan optimize` in the file located localy on my windows and also into the file into the virtual machine. I know that both file are linked, but I wanted to see if there was a problem with one of the machine.

So, now I can't use `php artisan <command>` and I don't know what to do/try. Can you please help me fixing this! It will be appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

It seems PHP is trying to inject a class `hash` but isn't able to resolve it. However, notice that the error describes the class name in lowercase. As you pointed out yourself, you probably need Laravel's well-known `Hash` facade.

Since PHP namespacing is case-sensitive, I suggest you check your Git commits to recent additions/modifications referencing the uncapitalized version of the facade.